# If $X_{k}\sim Bernoulli\left(p\right)$ then $\prod_{k=1}^{n}X_{k}\sim Bernoulli\left(p\right)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Part of investing a question about $Y=X_1X_2X_3$ where $X_i\sim Bernoulli\left(p\right)$, I tried to figure if the following statement is true:

> Let $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ be $n$ random independent variables so $X_{i}\sim Bernoulli\left(p\right)$. So $\prod_{k=1}^{n}X_{k}\sim Bernoulli\left(p\right)$.

I can't seem to figure out a way to prove it or disprove it. If the statement is not true, can we say something about the $\prod_{k=1}^{n}X_{k}$ so I could continue with my main question?

Comment: $\prod_{k=1}^n X_k=1\iff\forall k,X_k=1$ with a probability of $p^n$. The product equals $0$ when at least one $X_k$ is $0$, with a probability of $1-p^n$.

Comment: @Tuvasbien It depends what you call exactly a Bernouilli... Sometimes, this is just a variable that can take two values. Sometimes, the values are specified to be $0$ and $1$. (et je vais bien, merci)

Comment: For me, a Bernoulli takes the values $0$ and $1$ a.s. For instance if $X_i$ are in $\{-1,1\}$, this is what I call a Rademacher. (Ravi de le savoir)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depend of the state space of the $X_i$. For example, if $X_i\in\{0,1\}$

$$\mathbb P\left\{\prod_{i=1}^nX_i=1\right\}=\mathbb P\left\{X_1=1,...,x_n=1\right\}=p^n.$$

So, $$\prod_{i=1}^nX_i\sim Bernoulli(p^n).$$

If the $X_i$ are for example in $\{-1,1\}$, the product is still a Bernoulli, but it's a bit more complicated to find the parameter. And if the state space is $\{1,2\}$, then the product won't be Bernoulli.